# Plant with circle leaves and multiple bubs

Tags: flowers

I am wondering what kind of plant this is. It resembles somewhat of a fox tail but I have not found out what type of plant this is. It showed up in one of my flower plots and I have been letting it grow out. I have never seen anything like in my area. It has multiple leaves and buds and on the stem is a hint of red. Im just curious to know anything about this plant
[image: Picture of plant with buds]

I thank you for your time and appreciate all your help :D